# Limit parameter is not working when I add slick slider on related products

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, dependency

I want to add condition on related product where carousel should contain up to 12 products. For that I changed $limit variable and It's working fine without slider. But I added slider, value defined in $limit is not working. It's showing all the products.

app/design/frontend/Theme_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml

```
<ol class="products list items product-items pdp-product-slider" data-mage-init='{"carousel": "{}"}'>
```

app/design/frontend/Theme_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'carousel': 'Magento_Catalog/js/carousel',
    }
},
shim: {
    'carousel': {
        deps: 'Magento_Catalog/js/related-products'
    }
}};
```

app/design/frontend/Theme_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/web/js/carousel.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'slick'], function($) {
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.pdp-product-slider').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});})
```